How do I skip two await tasks?
I'm using Unity 2022.3.36f1 and using the UniTask library, but I think, missing some crucial basic understanding.
I'm trying to play one video, then another one afterward unless a "skip" action is called during either of the videos, which should stop them both and continue on down the code. It isn't working if you do the skip during the first vid - the second one still plays.
My external _isSkip boolean is either being reset back to false, or more likely it's using the initial value, in which case how do I get the WaitUntil to check the value at the time it is run?
private bool _isSkip;

private void SkipVideos() {
    _isSkip = true;
    Media.VideoStop();
}

private async UniTaskVoid StartMode() {
    // this called by StartMode().Forget();
    
    _isSkip = false;

    // video1 already playing, takes 7.1s

    // SkipVideos can be called during first await OR second, and it should skip BOTH videos
    await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(7140), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip == true));

    var delay = Media.VideoPlay("video2"); // returns millisecond length of video
    // if SkipVideos was called during first delay, when we get to here _isSkip is false, why?
    await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(delay), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip == true));

    // other code that should be done after both vids finish OR skip was triggered, go here...
}

I did initially start off trying to use cancellation tokens, but then the other stuff further down didn't run (?). I guess I could break into a sub Task but I'm really trying to have clean, clear and simple code - if it gets too wordy, I'll probably have to go back to Coroutines.
I was thinking Media.VideoPlay could be an async in the future for neatness, but leaving as-is for the question.

Well your code doesn't skip anything. It awaits any of the first two tasks and then continues to start and await any of the other two.
As both UniTask.Delay and WaitUntil return a typeless UniTask I would rather expect that this overload is being used UniTask<int> WhenAny(params UniTask[] tasks) which returns the index of the task that finished
so it should be e.g.
var index1 = await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(7140), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip == true));

if(index1 == 1)
{
    // skip pressed during first video
    ...
}
else
{

    var delay = Media.VideoPlay("video2"); // returns millisecond length of video
    var index2 = await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(delay), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip == true));

    if(index2 == 1)
    {
        // skip pressed during second video
        ...
    }
}

// other code that should be done after both vids finish OR skip was triggered, go here...

Note that this would still not actually cancel the other tasks once they are started - even if skip was pressed. They would not be awaited anymore but still run to the end. For a simple Delay that probably doesn't really matter but in case you want to do anything else there, you should rather use proper CancellationToken as well like e.g.
using(var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource());

var index1 = await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(7140, cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip, cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token));

if(index1 == 1)
{
    // skip pressed during first video
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    ...
}
else
{

    var delay = Media.VideoPlay("video2"); // returns millisecond length of video
    var index2 = await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(delay, cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token), UniTask.WaitUntil(() =>_isSkip, cancellationToken: cancellationTokenSource.Token));

    if(index2 == 1)
    {
        // skip pressed during second video
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        ...
    }
}

// other code that should be done after both vids finish OR skip was triggered, go here...


Alternatively of course it might be cleaner to just split this further out in two methods and then wrap this with the one that should skip.
So e.g. like
private async UniTask PlayBothVideos(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        // still not the best solution to hardcode this value
        await UniTask.Delay(7140, cancellationToken: token);
   
        var delay = Media.VideoPlay("video2");
        await UniTask.Delay(delay, cancellationToken: token);
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    {
        // this is expected. It just means we skipped
        // nothing to do but want catch the exception
    }
}

private async UniTask CheckForSkip(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await UniTask.WaitUntil(() => _isSkip, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    {
        // this is expected. It just means the videos finished first
        // nothing to do but want to catch the exception
    }
}

private async UniTaskVoid StartMode()
{
    using(var source = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var videoTask = PlayBothVideos(source.Token);
        var skipTask = CheckForSkip(source.Token);

        await UniTask.WhenAny(videoTask, skipTask);

        source.Cancel();
    }

    // other code that should be done after both vids finish OR skip was triggered, go here...
}


Actually now thinking about it further - all you need is a delay. So actually you could even further simplify the whole thing directly using the delay parameter of CancellationTokenSource and do
private async UniTask<bool> CheckForSkip(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        // if the delay finishes first this throws OperationCancelledException
        await UniTask.WaitUntil(() => _isSkip, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

        return true;
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException)
    {
        // this means the current video finished first
        return false;
    }
}

private async UniTaskVoid StartMode()
{
    using(var source = new CancellationTokenSource(7140))
    {
        if(await CheckForSkip(source.Token) == false)
        {
            // skipped during first video
        }
    }

    var delay = Media.VideoPlay("video2");

    using(var source = new CancellationTokenSource(delay))
    {
        if(await CheckForSkip(source.Token)
        {
            // skipped during second video
        }
    }

    // other code that should be done after both vids finish OR skip was triggered, go here...
}


Cancellation token throws an exception by default. So either a try-catch is needed, or a SuppressCancellationThrow() call for the deepest awaited tasks, in order for the "other code" to run.

@Vladimir good point thanks! I will come back to this as soon as I am not only on a text editor ^^

Thanks for the reply! I thought that the code just stopped at an await line? The examples all seem to just do await UniTask.Delay(7140) and following lines aren't hit until that expires. await UniTask.WhenAny seemed the obvious way of waiting for 'any' of multiple things. So what you're saying is that my entire StartMode evaluates immediately which is why _isSkip is showing false in the debugger at that line? 'Other code below' isn't running though. I guess that's where I'm not quite grokking it

The thing is, my code does wait at the first line until the time runs out or _isSkip is set to true. Then it moves down and does wait again at the second one. It's just that on that second one, it always thinks _isSkip is false (checked in debugger) even in that case where _isSkip was set true while vid1 was playing. If I press the button to trigger the skip to true again, it skips the second vid too and the lower down code runs. I do understand what you're saying about the cancellation tokens to clean up tasks properly, I'm just trying to understand what is going on here though

@MattKemp no await waits until the task is done .. and as you say await any waits until any of the tasks is done ... however your question sounded like you want to immediately skip the second video if you skipped during the first one .. so why even start tasks for the second then? And regarding the _skip having unexpected values ... could this be running on a different thread? bool itself isn't thread-save

the _isSkip value is the crux of my question. I've read that Unity and UniTask do all run on the same thread (unlike using the normal C# Task), so didn't think this might be what's happening. As you say, why run that second task at all, I guess I figured if _isSkip was being changed then it wouldn't matter and the second await would return immediately. I thought I might not be understanding the lambda in some way too. I'll move the _isSkip logic out and report back. Appreciate the help.

@Vladimir I'm still not a pro in task cancellation either ^^ Does it make sense now? :D

@derHugo Yep, it makes sense))

@MattKemp your _skip should work just fine. Can it be that it is set to false somewhere else? Or can StartMode be called again while still running?

@MattKemp simply use this code to test: public class Test : MonoBehaviour { bool _isSkip; async void Start() { UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ContinueWith(() => _isSkip = true).Forget(Debug.LogException); try { await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)), UniTask.WaitUntil(() => _isSkip)); Debug.Log(_isSkip); await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)), UniTask.WaitUntil(() => _isSkip)); }catch (Exception e) { Debug.LogException(e); } } }. It should output True. You can also put logs anywhere here including lambdas.

@MattKemp note that using the CancellationToken is the better option not only because it stops the running tasks, but also because if you cancel during the first video, it immediately moves execution to the catch block, and the second video doesn't even start.

You're awaiting your WhenAny, but aren't checking the return value. With the real Task.WhenAny, the pattern would be like:
var skipTask = // whatever task completes when skip is pressed, implemented with an `AsyncManualResetEvent` for example
var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(
    Task.Delay(7140), // incredibly bad code to measure video duration
    skipTask);
if(completedTask != skipTask) // skip not pressed?
{
    // play the second video, same pattern
}

// common code

Your silly little library doesn't implement a proper WhenAny, and instead seems to return a tuple with a boolean that's true if the left task is completed (?), so adjust the above to use it instead of comparing tasks:
if(await UniTask.WhenAny(UniTask.Delay(7140), UniTask.WaitUntil(() => _isSkip)) is (true, _))
{
    // skip not pressed
}


can you explain why checking _isSkip doesn't work? An issue with lambdas?
